# Analyse recursion $N_{t+1}=rN_t/(1+bN_t^2)$

Tags: limits, recursion

Given
$$N_{t+1}=\frac{rN_t}{1+bN_t^2}$$
for $r>0$ and $b>0$

I need to:

$1$. Find the limit of the recursion.

$2$. Prove that:
$$\frac{2r^2}{(4+r^2)\sqrt{b}}\le N_t \le \frac{r}{2\sqrt{b}}$$
for large enough $t$.

$3$. Prove that if $b>4$ then for some $t$ we have $N_t<1$.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. (Plus, most probably some typos or missing conditions or whatever.)

Comment: The thing is that I have managed to prove numerically 2 and 3 by the using of a cobweb. However I don't see a way to prove them analytically. All the information I have is written above. The context is a problem of biology, but that does not provide any mathematical hint. $N_t<1$ just means extintion of a species because there is less than one individual.

Answer (score 3):

The limit (if there is one) of any continuous recurrence relation must be a fixed point. That means in your case that if there is a limit $N$, it needs to statisfy
$$
N = \frac{rN}{1+bN^2}
$$
For $b = 4$ and $r = 2$, both sides of the inequality in point 2 is equal to $1/2$, while the sequence itself will *never* be exactly equal to that unless it starts out with $N_1 = \frac{1}{2}$, so the inequality will never hold in that case (I'm sure there are other cases as well).